# I'm think I've found a bug with JetPack 1.7

Tags: apache, xml, plugin-jetpack

There are dozens of other WP installs on the same server, subject to the same ModSec rules, and none of them has a problem. This is the only WP install that has jetpack installed and it only occurs when JetPack is active. The problem is as follows:

Some actions on the post/page edit screen (so far it **seems** to be the ones that don't refresh the URL, like UPDATE or configure featured image) show me the following alert:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ioa.png

The logs show:

```
Received From: kvm1->/var/log/httpd/error_log
Rule: 1002 fired (level 2) -> "Unknown problem somewhere in the system."
Portion of the log(s):
body.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty

ModSecurity: XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document. [hostname "www.mydomain.org"] [uri "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"] [unique_id "blablah"]

ModSecurity:  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/00_asl_z_antievasion.conf"] [line "36"] [id "330791"] [msg "Failed to parse request body.  This may be an impedence mismatch attack, a broken application or a broken connection.  This is not a false positive.  Check your application or client for errors."] [data "XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document."] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "REQBODY_ERROR" required. [hostname "www.mydomain.org"] [uri "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"] [unique_id "blablah"]
```

Jetpack is 1.7
WP is 3.4.1
Apache 2.2.15
PHP fCGId 5.3.3

Any ideas? The WP forum has been unresponsive so far. I've sent an email to JetPack support.

Comment: Given that it doesn't even happen in all cases for you, it's unlikely anyone would be able to accurately reproduce this to answer. Try contacting [Jetpack support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/?jetpack=needs-service).

Comment: I did already. It happens almost everytime I click UPDATE, but the exact condition I haven't been able to isolate yet.

Comment: Have you tried disabling mod_security specifically for calls to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php ? That might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hello Otto. If I do that then the problem will go away. But I dont think modsec is to blame here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetpack support kindly replied:

> This could be an issue with the After the Deadline module. When you
>   update a post, WordPress makes a call to the service
>   (service.afterthedeadline.com) to spellcheck your content, and it
>   seems an error occurs during the connection.
>
> Could you try deactivating the Spelling and Grammar module

Disabling it DID fix the problem. It seems that the module does not correctly handle its job when an updated post/page content is empty. The modsec rules are not to blame (Thank you @Otto).